# I am trying to use respondsToSelector but unable to get expected output can anyone find what is wrong in my code?

Tags: objective-c

```
#import "movie.h"
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // insert code here...
    movie *obj = [[movie alloc]init];
   [obj findinterestofnum1:(int)200 num2:(int)4 num3:(int)5];

    SEL suf = @selector(findinterestofnum1: num2:num3:);
    BOOL sul = [obj respondsToSelector:suf];

    if(sul)
    {
        NSLog(@"It is implememted");
    }

    else
    {
        NSLog(@" It is not implemented");
    }

    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
********-----
@interface movie : NSObject {
@private

}
-(void)findinterestofnum1:(int)p num2:(int)n num3:(int)r;

@end
*******-------
#import "movie.h"


@implementation movie

-(void)findinterestofnum1:(int)p num2:(int)n num3:(int)r
{
  int a ;
    a= (p*n*r/100);


    NSLog(@"interest value is =%d",a);

}




- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

i am trying to find whether method is implemented and if it is not it should print it is not implemented

Comment: What’s the output of this program when you run it?

Comment: @Bavarious  2011-04-21 13:32:19.845 usingselectors[918:903]    interest value is =40
2011-04-21 13:32:19.848                        usingselectors[918:903] It is implememted
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Those first two lines are fine but it’s odd that you don’t get the last `NSLog()`. Are you sure you have rebuilt your program after having added that `NSLog()` line?

Comment: @Bavarious I executed my code after deleting the implementation part in movie.h file it should actually print "it is not implemented"but still the output is "it is implemented".

Comment: Depending on how you’ve deleted the implementation part, you should get a warning about an incomplete implementation and a runtime error when trying to execute that method. Please edit your question and paste the **exact** code that you are running.

Comment: @Bavarious 
@implementation movie

-(void)findinterestofnum1:(int)p num2:(int)n num3:(int)r
{    }

Comment: So the method **is** implemented. It just so happens that it does nothing.

Comment: This is the way I deleted my implementation part not the whole code but the code inside flower brackets.

Answer (score 0):

@toddler, respondsToSelector just checks if the corresponding object can respond to that particular method. It doesn't do any checks on whether interface has that definition associated with it since it is a runtime check.

If you had removed the code from the implementation file (.m file) and not the interface, you would have got an error while executing it and you would have found that the BOOL sul is FALSE.